# Return the difference, in the first cell, between two cells with a certain value

Tags: excel, subtraction, excel-indirect

Goal: Return the date difference shown in cell `C5` to cell `C4`, and the date difference shown in `C6` to cell `C5` etc.

Currently I am getting the date difference of cells with the letter "s" but it is being shown in the next corresponding row with "s"

Formula currently in `C2` then dragged down is as shown below:

```
=IFERROR(IF(B2="s",A2-INDIRECT("A"&LOOKUP(2,1/($B$1:$B1="s"),ROW($B$1:$B1))),"-"),"n/a")
```

and this is how my sheet currently looks

[image: Current Sheet]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't for the life of me make sense of your goal. Can you provide the starting point and the expected result? A difference is between two values, which two values?

Comment: Sorry about that, what Column "C" is doing is finding rows with the letter "s" and taking the date and finding the difference of the next corresponding date with the letter "s" in the same row. What I'm trying to do is have the first row that has the letter "s" show the difference between the next row with the letter "s" instead of n/a (which is does since there is no prior row with the letter "s". Essential shift the differences found in column C up so there is an "N/A" in C15 and "1" in C4. Hope that's clearer, if not I'll try to explain it better!

Comment: You will get `N#/A` on the last "s" in that case (since there is not "next" "s" to get a value from). Is that OK?

Comment: Yep that is okay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula will look for the next "s", as long as it is within 1000 rows of the current one. Put this in `C2`:

```
 =IF(B2="s",INDEX(A3:A1002,MATCH("s",B3:B1002,0))-A2,"-")
```

Then populate down

To avoid the last "s" giving a result of `#N/A` you can wrap the whole thing in an `IFERROR` statement:

```
 =IFERROR(IF(B2="s",INDEX(A3:A1002,MATCH("s",B3:B1002,0))-A2,"-"),"-")
```